# how can i call Android hide Handler(boolean b) constructor?

Tags: java, android, reflection, handler

android.os.Handler class has a hide constructor --> void Handler(boolean async),

I just want to call this method by reflection,but in vain...

here is my code:

```
    Class clazz = Class.forName("android.os.Handler");
    Constructor construct = clazz.getConstructor(boolean.class);
    //Constructor construct = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(boolean.class);
    construct.setAccessible(true);

    boolean[] ailments = new boolean[]{true};
    Handler handler = (Handler) construct.newInstance(ailments);
```

the error message is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.Handler.<init>(boolean)

at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)....
```

I try to iterate the clazz.getConstructors() returns Constructor array, and log their ParamsType, just find Looper,Callback ...

why it can't log out 'boolean'?

```
public More ...Handler(boolean async) {
    this(null, async);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by importing the framework.jar instead of android.jar in android/sdk/platforms/android+versioncode/

adk had cut down the @hide api and internal classes to generate the android.jar,we can't use these resources unless we use framework.jar for developing.

see this project,it provided complete classes which included @hide api and internal classes.

[android-hidden-api](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call `construct.newInstance(true)` instead of passing the boolean as an array